# AWS IAM Deny access to update specific route in a VPC Route Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance that allowed to update routes in the route table. But I don't want it can update all routes.
I make these routes via CloudFormation and first I tried to make an export that refer to the specific route and deny access to resource:

```
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ec2:CreateRoute'
              - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaceAttribute'
              - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
              - 'ec2:DescribeRouteTables'
              - 'ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute'
              - 'ec2:ReplaceRoute'
              - 'ec2:DeleteRoute'
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Deny
            Action:
              - 'ec2:CreateRoute'
              - 'ec2:ReplaceRoute'
              - 'ec2:DeleteRoute'
            Resource: 
              - !ImportValue 'Devops-Dev-Route'
```

But I got an error "Resource DevVP-1PR60X60UDUJN must be in ARN format". And as I see there is no way to get ARN as AWS::EC2::Route has no such attribute.

The another try was to create VPC Managed prefix list witch contains all necessary CIDRS and deny access to it. CloudFormation stack deployed ok, but the role off course has access to all routes as this is two different resource types (AWS::EC2::Route and AWS::EC2::PrefixList)

Any suggestions how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

IAM does not support adding a specific route in the resources section of an IAM policy for EC2.

Reference: [List of supported resources for EC2 IAM policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-resources-for-iam-policies)

The route-table resource type corresponds to AWS::EC2::RouteTable and not AWS::EC2::Route. You can also refer the actions section in the above link for a list of resources supported for each individual action.

Comment: Thanks, very useful link!